# Drawing sub-pixel sized triangles (using Metal)

Tags: macos, metal

My program reads graphic shapes from file and then displays them using Metal. Sometimes the graphic shapes (or resulting triangles) are smaller/thinner than a pixel on screen, resulting in the shape to become invisible.

Is there way to make sure there are always some pixels drawn? Much like how drawing line primitives always results in 1 pixel wide lines.

Is this something I should do from the vertex shader? Or do I need to control the rasterizer?

Comment: One thing you could try is enabling [MSAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing), which will compute multiple samples along primitive edges, thus making subpixel triangles visible in proportion to how much of the pixel they cover. You could also use supersampling (rendering to a larger target and downscaling). There might be clever tricks you can pull with conservative rasterization, but I'm not familiar with how exactly that would work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem with using MSAA is that I also draw a grid using the line primitives. MSAA makes such a grid look very weird (when the grid lines are not pixel aligned).

Comment: You could get nice antialiased lines by drawing your grid with a [shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtlcWX). Rendering the grid as a [full-screen triangle](https://rauwendaal.net/2014/06/14/rendering-a-screen-covering-triangle-in-opengl/) wouldn't invoke MSAA. This approach would allow you to choose your own line AA scheme, including pixel-snapping when drawing screen-aligned grids. Just a thought.